# To match pattern from beginning - Perl

Tags: perl

I want to match the pattern if it's beginning with it.
Exa, here 'is' will pass the if condition because 'is' is a part of 'this'. I don't want that. I want that only if there's an 'is' word, only then it should pass.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$mysub= "is";
$str="this  good morning";

if($str=~ /$mysub/){
    print ("Here");
}
else
{
   print ("Not in it");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the "^" match begin of line operator.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$mysub= "is";
$str="this  good morning";

if($str=~ /^$mysub/){
    print ("Here");
}
else
{
   print ("Not in it");
}
```

Comment: +1 for managing to decode that question in 4 minutes. Uhm, though IMO all answers should use strict and warnings, even when the OP's code doesn't.

Comment: Lol, thanks! And do agree with using strict and warnings though usually try not to change the sample much when answering so the change is clearer.

But yes, @hello_hi, all your Perl should use those directive. Save you lots of headaches.

Comment: @TLP, I actually think it meant beginning of word, not string, so it's about `\b`.

Answer (score 4):

[asantaballa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995429/asantaballa) has given a good answer, in that the beginning of line anchor can be used to avoid matching `this` in this case. However, if you want to match inside the string, such as this:

```
my $str = "don't match this";
```

Then you can't use the circumflex `^`, but you can use word boundary instead:

```
if ($str =~ /\bis\b/) {
```

The word boundary will do what it says, match word boundaries, and will make sure you get no partial matches.

Also, you should never write code without these two pragmas:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Why? Because it will hurt your learning, make debugging harder and make your life more painful.

Comment: @daxim You should not make changes like this to other people's answer. In [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) it is referred to as "caret or circumflex accent". If you have sources that trumps that, post them in comment.

Comment: Correcting mistakes is de rigueur for this site, don't be surprised. perlre is using the wrong word, too, but I cannot correct it as easily. Source: http://isbn.nu/0321480910

Comment: An edit makes you say something in my name, so you'd better make it for a good point. In this case, you are promoting a name that is different from what I've learned, and different from the docs, and your only support for this is a picture of a book. I am all for learning new things, but you have a poor way to present your source. Here is a source that uses both names: http://www.ascii-code.com/

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use diagnostics;

my $mysub= "is";
my $str="this  good morning";

if($str=~ /\W+$mysub\W+/){
    print ("Here");
}
else
{
   print ("Not in it");
}
```

Added diagnostics to get problem info about your code, which reported missing declaration of $mysuf and $str.

Also used \W+ as delimiters, they match anything non \w.

Comment: I'd like to know the reason for the downvote if it isn't too much to ask.

Comment: Your regex won't work if `is` is at the beginning, or end, of the string. Instead of `\W+` I would use `\b`, as that is it's reason for existence. Also you would only need `\W` not `\W+` as this is not an anchored matc. You could instead do a zero width negative lookahead, and negative lookbehind `/(?<!\w)is(?!\w)/`. To use a positive lookahead would be more complex `/(?<!\w)is(?=\W|$)/`. ( You can't even do that with the lookbehind because it will be a variable width )